Geo Nodes - 'Dashed Line' Connectors: How Do They Work?

So I found out that affine texture mapping is really simple to recreate in geo nodes and thought I'd give it a go, and whilst the guide I followed to do so worked flawlessly, I wanted to rearrange the node setup such that the UVMap attribute was written to directly in the geo node setup. I didn't think this would be a problem, and yet it was down to my ignorance of some geo nodes fundamentals I'm hoping you guys can help me on:

Why do the two examples in the image above give two different outputs? As far as I can tell, both examples achieve the same goal and all that changes is how the shader nodes interact with the result. I understand that dashed line connectors in geo nodes represent function flow and solid line connectors represent data flow, but I don't really know what the difference between the two is. From what I can understand from examining my examples, it would seem dashed line connectors can have inputs at the end of the connector affect the output at the start of the connector, but how and why?
Many thanks for reading!

The difference is simple. While Geometry nodes are calculated on some domain (like vertices, edges, faces or in your case face corners), shaders are calculated on each pixel on the screen. Let's look at a simple example. Here I made a plane with a vertex group, each point except one has 0.5 weight, and bottom left has 1 weight:

Now, you can divide UV coordinates by vertex weight. It will double values except one corner, which will stay the same.

If you multiply UV back by vertex weight, you will get back UV values as if they have not changed:

But if we multiply UV in shader, we will make this multiplication in shader in every point of the surface. In this case, that will happen, for example, in the center of the plane?

Note how non-uniform vertex color is drawn by vertex shader:

In GPU meshes are drawn by triangles, so it is not possible to interpolate vertex weights on plane, instead it interpolates on 2 triangles.
Imagine that you want to calculate a point in the center of the plane. It is on this triangle:

Bottom-left point has UV (0,0) and weight 1. Top-right point has UV (2,2) and weight 0.5. So point in between has to have UV (1,1) and weight 0.75. If you multiply these you will get UV (0.75, 0.75) instead of normal (0.5, 0.5)

I think I understand now, I just wasn't in the right mindset. From recent OpenGL projects I know about vertex and fragment shaders and the graphics pipeline they follow and I had just yet to make the comparison in my head that shader nodes and geo nodes are equivalent to fragment shaders and vertex shaders respectively. If I understand correctly: I have to multiply the UVs in shader nodes because setting data per-vertex and then reading data per-fragment is what makes the UV multiplication skewed/interpolated for the affine mapping effect? At least, that's the sense I make of it. Thank you!
